# Turn existing git repos into submodules of parent project

Tags: git, shell

I have several, unversioned projects which in turn contain a large number of plugins, some of which are git clones. I now want to turn the parent project into a git repo, preferably without having to go through all the plugins, identifying which are git repos, and manually convert them to submodules of the parent project (which is, of course, the desired outcome).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in plugins/*
do
    if [ -e "$d/.git" ]
    then
        # Unstage the gitlink, so we can then add it back as a submodule:
        git rm --cached "$d"
        # Guess that the URL for origin is a reasonable one to use:
        URL="$(cd "$d" && git config remote.origin.url)"
        # Add the git repository back as a submodule:
        git submodule add "$URL" "$d"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Does not "git submodule add" require the path to the origin as well?

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen: oops, yes - I've corrected my answer, assuming that `origin` is a plausible remote in each submodule.

Comment: Thanks! However, this gives me a "[plugin/path] already exists in the index" error.

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen: ah, interesting - so are these git repositories already stored as gitlinks, and you just want to turn them into submodules?  What do you get if you do `git ls-tree HEAD:plugins` (or whatever the directory is)?  (If they're gitlinks, I would expect the lines to begin `160000 commit`.)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. Those that are git repositories seem to begin with "160000 commit" (as apposed to "040000 tree" for the others).

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen: OK - in that case I think you just need to unstage the gitlink before re-adding it as a submodule.  I've added a `git rm --cached "$d"` to the script in my answer to do that.

Comment: Running that gives me "fatal: pathspec 'plugin/path' did not match any files"

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen: assuming the path `plugin/path` is right, you'd get that error if that gitlink had already been unstaged (e.g. from an earlier run of a script) or if it has a trailing slash - I guess it might be the former?

Comment: Actually, it was the trailing slash. Sorry about that. Now it seems to work great - thanks a bunch!